# Prolog transformation of arguments into a list

Tags: prolog

If I had the predicate `cat(dog(cow(a,b,c)))`, how I can transform this into `cat(dog(cow([a,b,c])))`?
I was thinking about the system's predicate `=..` but it doesn't end properly, because I obtain `cat([dog([cow([a,b,c])])])`, and that's not that I want :(
The patch needs to fix also other similar case as `dog(cat(a,b,c))` into `dog(cat([a,b,c]))`.

Anyone has an idea? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong with the operators...

My idea is:

```
animal(X) :- atomic(X).
animal(X) :- atomic([]).

cow(X) :-
   animal(X),
   cow([X|List]).

dog(X) :-
   animal(X),
   dog([X|List]).

cat(X) :-
   animal(X),
   cat([X|List]).
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Use `=..` with a check for ternary functors.

```
ternary_takes_list(T0, T) :-
    (T0 =.. [F, X, Y, Z] ->
        T =.. [F, [X, Y, Z]]
    ; T0 =.. [F, X0] -> 
        ternary_takes_list(X0, X),
        T =.. [F, X]
    ;
        T = T0
    ).
```

This works on your examples:

```
?- ternary_takes_list(cat(dog(cow(a,b,c))), X).
X = cat(dog(cow([a, b, c]))).

?- ternary_takes_list(dog(cat(a,b,c)), X).
X = dog(cat([a, b, c])).
```

Comment: It's work!
Thanks so very much, this problem get me crazy in this days.

Comment: @DracyEnzo: if this answer is sufficient, then please click the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Hi
I had done more other tests, and i had another problem with this code.
The code will be work if i had variable parameters.
Es.
cat(dog(cow(a,b,c,d,e))).
If i try more of 3 or less of 3 parameters, the code doesn't work.

Comment: @DracyEnzo: handling that takes a trivial modification to the code that I will leave to you.

Comment: I think that i will use a recuersive call, but i'm not sure how.
I was thinking to add a counter into predicate, that is the length of the members of the list, but if i had only 1-2 atoms i had the same problem..
Sorry for the incomplete information, i was thinking that "a, b, c" were an example that represent anything, but i had to specific that the arity of the predicate was undefinite (1 to n).
The other problem of recursive call is the basic case, the basic case will be when i had 1 atom, but in fact..i had always only 1 atom (that will be repeated more times).

Comment: @DracyEnzo: no need for recursion. Just change the pattern matching logic.

Comment: I had thinked this possible solutions:
1. add variable into (T0 =.. [F, X, Y, Z], but i don't think that's the correct method, because if i 2 or less atoms or more atoms of variable, the program didn't work.
2. call ternary_takes_list more times and merge the list (but isn't a good idea, because then i will add more other controls, and also is not more elegant.

Comment: @DracyEnzo: replace `T0 =.. [F, X, Y, Z]` with `(T0 =.. [F|Xs], length(Xs, N), N > 1)` and adapt the rest accordingly.

Comment: Hi
I had done this modify, but i can't understand what i wrong.
I write the entire code:
ternary_takes_list(T0, T) :-
    ((T0 =.. [F|Xs], lengths(Xs, N), N > 1):-
           T =.. [F, [Xs];
           T0 =.. [F, X0] :-
              ternary_takes_list(X0, X),
              T =.. [F, Xs]
    ;
        T = T0
    ).
    
lengths(L, N) :-
          lengths(L, 0, N).
          lengths([], ACC, ACC).
   lengths([_|TAIL], ACC, N) :-
           ACC1 is ACC+1, 
           lengths(TAIL, ACC1, N).